# .NET WinForms HTML editor component

Tags: .net, html, winforms, editor, html-editor

We're looking for a .NET component for HTML editing in WinForms. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor) post, and that's kind of what we're using now, but it's pretty old and crufty, I'm looking for a cleaner solution. I don't really have the time (or right now, the inclination) to write our own from scratch...and am hoping there's a commercial/free solution out there. I've looked at the Netrix Component and am not overly impressed initially...is there anything else out there?

Comment: Hm, I'm fine w/ closing as off-topic, is there a place to go to ask for component recommendations like this one?

Answer (score 4):

You may try .NET Win HTML Editor Control from SpiceLogic, it is not free, but highly featured. Here is the link:

https://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-WinForms-HTML-Editor-Control-8

And here is an image with feature highlights.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a pretty decent free one at...

http://windowsclient.net/articles/htmleditor.aspx

It has limitations...but then again...it is free.  I have used this control for a couple of non-commercial applications.

Seth

Comment: This is actually the one we're using now (albeit very very very heavily modified) :)

Comment: I did read your link to that post...but it seemed like a different control.  The namespace for the one I referenced is Microsoft.MicrosoftConsultingService.HTMLEditorControl.  or something like that and that code sample is referencing WebControl rather than HTMLEditorControl. 

Anyway sorry for the misdirect.  I think to get better than that one your gonna have to cough up some dough.

Good Luck.

Seth

Comment: The hyperlink in your answer doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Here's another link to an [HTML editor](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WinForms-HTML-Editor-01dbce1a/sourcecode?fileId=25712&pathId=371288050) on MSDN; not sure if it's the same as the one in the answer but does the trick! Looks as though it pulls from the mshtml library (IE).

Answer (score 1):

I love [xstandard](http://www.xstandard.com) myself. Not cheap, but damned good for everything I have used it for.