# is it is possible to add tinyMCE editor in vb.net 2008?

Tags: vb.net

how can i add the tinyMCE editor in my vb.net desktop application ..please explain

Answer (score 0):

tinyMCE is an html control and must run in a browser. This question appears to be a duplicate that was already answered fairly well. [winforms html editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor)

There are also WinForm controls available that you could try like http://windowsclient.net/articles/htmleditor.aspx. I've never used it myself (I just found it), but it might work for you.