# C# Winforms WebBrowser edit html

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want to display a webpage in a WebBroswer in my winforms application. I however want to use some custom css to change how the page looks. Is it possible to attach a style sheet and edit the html page you are viewing?

Comment: maybe you can open webpage with javascript:void(document.designMode="on") so this will force page to be edited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [winforms html editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this web control http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx
and save it as a web page and load and you can show the source in another text box , once changes are made you can save to a temp file and load it. There is an option to view local file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that kind of thing is supported.. but anyway that would be a **horrible** thing to do. you may end-up interfering with the CSS used by the client page.

*Have you ever seen your browser override your CSS used by page and say i want to show it this way. (I know development tools like firebug,etc do it)*

Comment: The website page has very little styling.I want to add a css file to the browser so that the fonts, colors etc are consistent with the style of out application.