# How do I make a chat like interface/display?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, .net-4.0

Basically, I want to have a chat like interface - one line with name and time, the next few lines with a message.

In HTML / ASP.Net (or any other web language), this is obviously easy - build a component and just have multiple copies for each chat object.

I have been trying on winforms, and the closest I have come is a TreeView list, but it does not look at all pretty!

I was just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction of what I need to do to achieve a nice formatted text box in the style of chat applications?

Comment: How about webbrowser control?

see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor 
for example

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's any easier in ASP.Net than it is in Winforms. Try the RichTextBox control - you can control the entire layout (for the most part).

Answer (score 1):

You should use some kind of list view. At least it's the way it's done in WPF. Should be possible in Forms, too.

Comment: Customizing ListViews in Winforms is not even close to as good as it is in WPF - you will get frustrated quickly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ListView and edit the template. At least it's how I've done it in the past.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.layouttemplate.aspx