# Why is the HTML SCRIPT tag not subject to the same origin policy

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, standards

I am asking this questions because we will develop an application that is supposed to share cross origin data via javascript. One possible solution seems JSONP as it uses SCRIPT tags pull data from other domains. However, I would like to avoid the situation that we implement our awesome code on the assumption that the SCRIPT tag is not subject to sop and at some point browsers prohibit this functionality.

Can anybody shed some light on what is the reason for the SCRIPT tag to allow cross domain requests?

Comment: For the same reason that <img> tags aren't subjected to it.

Comment: What would that reason be and how does it apply to (executable) scripts?

Comment: The same origin policy is, in a way, actually why script tags to other domains are safe.  You don't exactly accidentally include a script tag in your markup (hopefully not anyway), but you can't guarantee the safety of the code you do include if you don't control it.  You may want to include some JS so that you can have ads on your page, but you will not want that ad website to have access to your users' session cookies.

Comment: @mosch look at it like this... they are subjected to the SOP in the same way as images, styles, etc. in that you can't get at the actual data itself. Just like you can't get at the text content of a cross origin stylesheet, or the pixels of a cross origin image with canvas, you can't get at the actual text content of a cross-origin script either. It plays by the same rules in that respect. But, yes, including scripts from untrusted third parties is sketchy.

Comment: This is an interesting discussion. From reading JSONP on wikipedia it lead me to read about [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) as a modern alternaitve to JSONP. It could address your concerns about future proofing your development.

Comment: @DaggNabbit "_they are subjected to the SOP in the same way as images, styles, etc._" As in, not really subject to it. They can still be read cross origin which is a plain violation of the security policy.

Comment: @curiousguy How can they be read?

Comment: @SurajJain You don't have read access, you have execute access to scripts and CSS.

Comment: @curiousguy `They can still be read cross origin which is a plain violation of the security policy` ,You said this, how can they be read cross origin?

Comment: @SurajJain They are read by the browser and run in the context of another page. If you disagree that it's plainly a security violation, please specify which security property is not violated.

Comment: @curiousguy But the data is not available to user script in browser. The data is always fetched but browser makes sure that it is not available to user script.

Comment: @SurajJain Again, spell out the *security property* that's enforced here. Or admit it's a security violation.

Comment: @curiousguy I am saying you are saying that they are not subjected to SOP, I want to know why is that? if you say because browser download it, image is also downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

I suppose [this draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-abarth-principles-of-origin-00) titled "Principles of the Same-Origin Policy" explains (albeit briefly) what's pretty much in everyone's head:

> In principle, user agents could treat every URL as a separate principal and isolate each document from every other URL unless the document explicitly indicated that it trusted that URL. Unfortunately, this design is cumbersome for developers because web applications often consist of a number of resource acting in concert.
>
> As an approximation, user agents group URLs together into protection domains called origins. In particular, two URLs are part of the same origin (i.e., represent the same principal) if they have the same scheme, host, and port.

In short: it would be much harder to build the Web if everything was subject to SOP.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer, this is also what GGG's link seems suggests (about images) but what I don't see is why do I have a same origin policy when there are easy methods to circumwent it? And how could I be certain that in five years, browsers still make JSONP possible?

Comment: @mosch: JSONP requires that the client and server explicitly cooperate and that the client fully trusts the server; I wouldn't call this an easy method. And what makes it work is a "protocol" between client and server that the user agent knows nothing about. It's like asking "how can I be certain that in five years browsers will still not refuse to load stylesheets from URLs that contain `foo`".

Answer (score 3):

The reason is because of legacy. It was built that way many years ago and if it changes now, too many sites will fail. Plus the security implications are well known, since it has been around for so long.