# What html tags are not affected by same origin policy?

Tags: html, same-origin-policy

I have read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530554/why-is-the-html-script-tag-not-subject-to-the-same-origin-policy) about same origin policy regarding the `script` tag. My situation is: I have two domain to manage (host differently) and need to share some (actually a lot) resources (particularly like js, css and some media). I would like to ask whether the following tags are actually affected or not affected if the source is from another domain:

```
<script> <img> <audio> <link rel="stylesheet"> (possibly <video>)
```

From the page linked above, it seems that I can wrote html for domain B which can have `<script>` tags directly link to domain A, but I cannot do that for css. Is that always correct? Must I copy the css file of domain A to domain B if I want to use them?

Comment: No, you can include external CSS by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can include external css same way you would include js !

do it like this in your head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    href="your_file_name.css">
```

Comment: I did. I got a error in my console: `Font from origin 'http://www.***.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` So that is not the issue of the css file? I am not using Ajax in my js file.

Comment: Loading CSS is fine, load it from CDNs for common libraries.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. Yes I am trying to load the `HTML-Kickstart` library [link](http://www.99lime.com/elements/). They are not providing CDN.

Comment: @epascarello May I also ask why CDN is not affected by same origin policy?

Comment: @XiaojunChen CSS is not subject to the same-origin policy, but font files are -- that error is complaining about the font specifically.