# If same origin policy is exempted for <script> tags then how does it help us?

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

The following questions are related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530554/why-is-the-html-script-tag-not-subject-to-the-same-origin-policy) on SO.

I am confused about the web-security model. When I make a request to a script via an Ajax call on another domain, the same-origin policy blocks me.

That's fine but when a script tag tries to load a **script from an external origin it is allowed**. That's strange. Same applies for `<link>` tags, for example I can load the bootstrap stylesheet from a CDN.

**I can also use a element injection directly into the DOM via javascript** and execute my script. Also I can use techniques like JSONP, so all these begs the question, **what the same-origin is protecting us from.**

Why are all the relaxations applied while straightforwards requests denied ?

Comment: You are in control of which external scripts you load onto your page. You are *not* in control of external scripts which attempt to access your page.

Comment: I think CORS saves from the following scenerio: With one tab opened you cannot access the other tabs of different domains. If you could then, for example, if someone opened your website and facebook in another tab then your website could communicate with facebook page and steal important imformation. But this is my opinion -- I might be wrong.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yeah so what's the use of having the same-origin policy ? A malicious page can just inject a `<script>` tag into the DOM and use the malicious script cross-domain, if I am not wrong.

Comment: @ng.newbie — What information would leak from Bob's site if Mallory loaded a script from it into her site? Only information the script was designed to expose … and scripts generally shouldn't include confidential data anyway, that's why JSONP can be used to hack around the Same Origin Policy (because Bob has to write the JSONP so that it leaks the information across origins deliberately).

Comment: @user31782 — You are confusing CORS and the Same Origin Policy. They are related but very different things.

Comment: @Quentin May be I meant same origin policy. What I meant is that you can download resources like style sheets, javascript files and images from other domains. But you can't upload anything, i.e. with ajax you can not send any data to other domain. Also ng.newbie plz see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27294846/3429430  --- The CSRF attack.

Comment: @user31782 — "with ajax you can not send any data to other domain" — Yes, you can. You just can't read the response.

Comment: Ok plz forget what ever I said. I am wrong.

Comment: @Quentin "What information would leak from Bob's site if Mallory loaded a script from it into her site? " Well what if it wasn't a script from Bob's site but a script written by Mallory hitting specific POST urls, lets say for funds transfer. Correct me if I am wrong but that would work right ? Or let's a malicious script is loaded via a normal script tag, without CSRF I could post any data using the users cookies right ? So if SOP is exempted for `<script>` tags then how does it help me ? That's my question.

Comment: "a script written by Mallory hitting specific POST urls, lets say for funds transfer" — That has nothing to do with leaking information though. It wouldn't need to include a script, the requests could be made directly to the POST URLs. That's a CSRF attack and (as the duplicate question says) the Same Origin Policy doesn't defend against that. (The standard defence for CSRF is a Synchronizer token and it is the same origin policy that stops a synchronizer token from being stolen though).

Comment: The Same Origin Policy is about “DOM access” - i.e., can you read the password the user just typed into that login form in that other frame, stuff like this. Merely _loading_ external resources has nothing to do with the SOP.

Comment: @Quentin Ok I think I am getting a hang of this. I just have a few doubts, according to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27294846/7134737) SOP is mostly for AJAX requests. Now let's take google-maps, I can obviously load it using a script tag since script tags are exempted from SOP policy. But how does google-maps change its map location if it communicates via AJAX , so where is the SOP policy there ? It communicates to google servers via ajax calls.

Comment: See "CORS" and "Alternatives to CORS" in the accepted answer on the duplicate quesiton.

Comment: @Quentin Okay so am I right in assuming that google-maps allows CORS in all its AJAX requests ? Even then I can use something like JSONP to violate CORS completely. Lets say I write a JS code that adds a bunch of `<script>` tags to my page, which all are JSONP tags. Granted I can only do GET requests **but that still violates CORS.**

Comment: "Okay so am I right in assuming that google-maps allows CORS in all its AJAX requests ?" — No idea. I assume that its API allows it under at least some conditions. I've not written any code that uses that API.

Comment: "Lets say I write a JS code that adds a bunch of `<script>` tags to my page, which all are JSONP tags." — JSONP requires that Bob provides the data in JSONP. It's a hack around the Same Origin Policy that must be supported by the data provider … **as the duplicate question says**