# Why and how is same origin policy exempted in script tags?

Tags: html, security, browser, same-origin-policy

I have a very simple question. Why and how is the same origin policy exempted for things like scripts, links img ?

I believe scripts and links are loaded using GET in a similar manner as calling a server API. So what is the difference. Why exempting this policy in these tags can't harm us.

I found this ([Why is the HTML SCRIPT tag not subject to the same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530554/why-is-the-html-script-tag-not-subject-to-the-same-origin-policy)) only question on SO, which doesn't have satisfying answers and not even an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a GET request (even with cookies) is not harmful; GET requests are not supposed to have any side-effects.

None of these tags allow the calling page to (directly) read responses, so they don't leak information.

Therefore, there is (almost) nothing wrong with allow it.

Comment: I understand GET is idempotent at the server's end. But can it not make any changes at the client using the response. Probably I didn't understand    --  **None of these tags allow the calling page to (directly) read responses, so they don't leak information.** How are the response used then??

Comment: They're executed or displayed on screen, but not exposed directly to Javascript.

Comment: Sorry but I still have a question, which context are they executed in. Even if in the global context, they can make changes to global variables/function (if they wanted to).

Comment: Yes, but that's up to the remote script.

Comment: So when I am loading CDNs, am I on the mercy of providers to not interfere with our code. Seems completely absurd to me though....!!!!!!

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari: Yes; you must never load a script from a server that you don't completely trust.