# Best control for rendering HTML

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, html-rendering

I have the need to render some html text (not an html page with `<html>` and `<body>` tags and everything, just some `<i>`'s and `<hr />`s and stuff) in a C# .NET 4.0 Winforms application. Preferably it would be a `Panel`-like control that you could just `p.HTML = "somehtml"` on and it would display HTML. Has anyone had any experience with .NET HTML rendering controls that they could recommend? I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/HtmlRenderer.aspx) on codeproject but I'm a little wary of stuff on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the build in `WebBrowser` control. You can always enclose your html snippet in standard `<html/>` markup.

```
string html = "<i> some text </i>";
webbrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format("<html>{0}</html>", html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor)

> You can use the WebBrowser control in
>   design mode with a second WebBrowser
>   control set in view mode.
>
> In order to put the WebBrowser control
>   in design mode, you can use the
>   following code.
>
> This code is a super stripped down
>   version of a WYSIWYG editor for one of
>   our software products.
>
> Simply create a new form, drop a
>   WebBrowser control on it, and put this
>   in the form_load

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")
Application.DoEvents()
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(False).Write("<html><body><div id=""editable"">Edit this text</div></body></html>")

'turns off document body editing
For Each el As HtmlElement In Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All
    el.SetAttribute("unselectable", "on")
    el.SetAttribute("contenteditable", "false")
Next

'turns on editable div editing
With Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.All("editable")
    .SetAttribute("width", Me.Width & "px")
    .SetAttribute("height", "100%")
    .SetAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
End With

'turns on edit mode
Me.WebBrowser1.ActiveXInstance.Document.DesignMode = "On"
'stops right click->Browse View
Me.WebBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
```