# HTML editor/viewer for an email program

Tags: c#, html-email, html-editor

I'm looking into HTML editors/textboxes for a small e-mail client I'm writing.

Or I may even be asking the wrong question, or in actuality thinking about it in the wrong way! Such as in Outlook, eM Client, and I'd imagine every other email client that can send HTML.

How would I get (or make) a control using Visual Studio/C# that mimics the email viewers/composing components of the aforementioned existing program examples?

I've tried researching this topic, but I don't really get the results I'm looking for. The closest I've gotten are:

- To some degree use a RichTextbox?
- For the VIEWING part, a web browser control.

What I'm looking for is obviously possible to do, I just can't find HOW to do it or how programs like Outlook are doing it already.

Comment: Looking at what Outlook does it like asking a burning man for fire safety tips (it uses an engine based on Word). See [winforms html editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor)

Comment: You're basically looking for a wysiwyg html editor control.

Answer (score 1):

Although this kind of question is a little broad for Stack Overflow, I felt obligated to answer because of good experiences I've had with this.  I would strongly encourage you to check our Telerik's suite of controls.  Sounds like you want to do some kind of desktop client, so I would check out their Winforms and/or WPF controls for this:
http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx 
http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/overview.aspx

They also have similar controls to create a web-based mail client, so if you create a service layer to do all your data retreival, you could conceivably create several client types and re-use all your service calls.

Here is a mail client demo they created using their controls:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/webmail/

And no, I don't work for Telerik.  Just a huge fan.  :-)