# C# WYSIWYG HTML Editor in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, html, winforms, editor

[Sample Html Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obkjB.png)

There is an html editor like the one in the picture. I searched a lot but I could not find a way .. Please Help. :(

Comment: [webbrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214124/winforms-html-editor) [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WinForms-HTML-Editor-01dbce1a)

Comment: I want Toolbox Item Please

Comment: the msdn example did have such toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [spicelogic](http://www.spicelogic.com/Products/NET-Win-HTML-Editor-Control-8) and [netrix](https://netrix.codeplex.com/)
or put one of the above editors in a `WebBrowser` control.

Hope will it help.

Comment: but spicelogic trial , netrix no download.. :(

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged in Stack Overflow, the same that asking for software recomendations.

Comment: I Use WebBrowser. But show MessageBox "this document has been Modified ,do you want to save changes?" How I Can Hide It?

Answer (score 0):

I Use WebBrowser. But show MessageBox "this document has been Modified ,do you want to save changes?" How I Can Hide It?